# Attach page to all root page trees

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, wagtail

In wagtail how would I attach a root page (and it's tree) to all sites root pages?

e.g. - I have sites 1.com, 2.com with root pages set to 1 Home Page, 2 Home Page under the wagtail "Root".

Now... let's say these sites both share a blog.... How do I set the blog to both of these sites? I'd have to add it under their root pages individually which is redundant.

Moreover, this is a more general problem since sites can also share static pages. So, since wagtail uses a tree structure should I just add an extra level to the root? Even doing this.... I'd then have to override teh serve in the root page I set to proxy the proper pages I want.

This seems very clumsy. Given that wagtail can manage differnt sites easily I think I'm overlooking something that helps interllink pages between sites.

Comment: You cannot put pages under two parents but here is a potentially similar question about content across multiple sites: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47088231/8070948

Comment: @LBBenJohnston Thanks for the link that'll work. I do have one additional queston if you don't mind I can't seem to resolve. Is it possible to proxy a wagtail `@route` view to use a pre-existing view. e.g. - I have a session wizard view built with a bunch of form logic. Moved to wagtail. I simply want to the new route to just serve this pre-existing wizard. Trying to replicate that in the view under the model would be a nightmare.

Comment: If you know the route in advance, or know it won't change - a hacky way to do that would be to set the URLs for the wizard before you set your Wagtail URLs in your urls.py - this would mean that those routes would never reach Wagtail routing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I just proxied it through the route by keeping my views.py and calling SessionWizard.as_view()(request, self, *args, **kwargs) and seems to work fine for any class based viewed. Or, functions could be used similarly.

Comment: @LBBenJohnston Sorry to bug you again since you've already helped me a lot... But, you seem knowledgable about wagtail would appreciate it if you could provide insight into my new question. Instead of it going potentially unnoticed in the feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wagtail uses [Materialized Path trees from django-treebeard](http://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mp_tree.html) which ensure there is always one path for every node. The Wagtail 'root' mentioned is the core root for all pages, with each site having a node with that main root as the parent.

This means that there is no simple way to have a page with two parents, which also means you cannot have the same page in two sites.

Depending on your requirements, a similar question about sharing content across sites could help:

[Wagtail MultiSite - Cross posting content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953972/wagtail-multisite-cross-posting-content/47088231)